# Need an example to show the need to check the closure property for being a subgroup under binary operation $\star$ of $(G, \star)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am able to theoretically sink in the idea as given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2070106/does-a-set-g-need-to-be-closed-under-a-binary-operation-star-for-g-star), but still need few simple examples. I mean that examples be of real, integer, rational domain and binary operations defined on them; or of rotations. Need this to really be familiar with the intricacies involved with the idea.

Comment: Sorry but I am not completely sure: what are you exactly asking for? an example of "weird" group or an explanation of why a subgroup is defined how it is defined?

Comment: @57Jimmy I cannot understand why "'weird' group" is referred to by you. Need some more elaboration by what you meant. Do you mean that only 'weird' groups are possible in which a portion of the set of group is not a subgroup?

Comment: @57Jimmy I am clear about defn. of subgroups, but the closure property check is what confuses me.

Comment: you seem to be complaining, in your question, that the only examples you know are easy ones. That's why I've asked if you wanted some definition of more complicated ("weird") groups.

Comment: @57Jimmy I hope the edit makes the meaning clear, as I meant the reverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A group is just a bag of elements with an operation defined between them. (And a couple of special properties)

A *subgroup* is just a group inside a group. For example the integers with addition are a group. Take your bag full of integers and pick some integers, putting them in a second bag. Is that second bag a subgroup of the integers? Only if the second bag itself is a group! But for the second bag to be a group, the binary operation must make sense inside that bag.

I.e. take the second bag to be $\{1, 3, 4\} $. Does integer addition make sense in the universe of the second bag? Not really, because $3+4 = 7 \not\in \{1,3,4\} $

That is why you need a subgroup to be closed under the binary operation.

Comment: I hope this simple example is enough to understand the reason. Though, would be more satisfied if could get slightly more complex examples.

Comment: Also, for infinite sets either do not need to check for closure under the binary operation (to check for being a sub-group); or am unclear about the infinite set based groups' subgroups.

Comment: @ijen I still can't see what is the problem: most subsets of a group are not subgroups, both finite and infinite. Hence you do need to check the closure to see if a subset is a subgroup.

Comment: @jiten you can create more complex examples with a lot of ease. Just take groups you know and randomly pick a couple of elements. More often than not you won't get a group. Take $f(x) = x+2 $ and $g(x) = x^2$ from the group of real functions with function composition as binary operation. Is the set $\{f,g\} $ a subgroup? It doesn't even have the identity, but ignoring that fact, notice that  $f(g (x)) = x^2+2 \not\in \{f,g \} $

Comment: @RGS I hope your example is a good example for failure of closure under binary operation for infinite sets. But, the identity and hence inverse properties are not satisfied, so may be need a different example.

Comment: @jiten you should be able to modify my *bag of functions* such that it contains the identity and the inverses of the functions you put, and even so without the bag being closed under function composition.

Comment: @RGS Let me try: if $f(x) = x+2$ and $g(x) = x+1$ from the group of real functions with function composition as binary operation, with identity $0$; then is the set $\{f,g\}$ a subgroup? $f(g(x)) = x + 3$. I feel I am stuck, as cannot clearly say if $x+3$ is following closure or not. I feel that the composition has the same identity ($0$).

Comment: You have $f(g(x)) = x+3$, which is neither the function $f$ nor the function $g$, so the set $\{f,g\}$ is not a subgroup, because it is not closed under function composition. (Also note that for function composition the identity is the function $i(x) = x$).

Comment: @RGS Thanks for the pointer. But, if for function composition the identity is the function $i(x) = x$, then what is the identity of the function $f(x) = x +2$.

Comment: @RGS You are correct in stating that identity is its own inverse. But, finding the identity of $f(x) = x+2$ is confusing. If I state it as $x =-2$, then $f(x) = 0$.

Comment: @jiten consider also $A:=\mathbb{Z} \backslash \{-1,1\}$. This has a $0$ and is closed under inversion, but it is not closed under the group operation, since for instance $3+(-2)=1$ and $1 \notin A$.

Comment: @RGS If you could please give some hint to my earlier comment regarding the identity of $f(x) = x +2$, as identity is its own inverse. Now, let identity be given by element $x'$, with inverse given by the equality: $f(x') = x' + 2 = x'$. I am confused about it. Please guide.

Comment: @jiten $f(x)$ has no identity of its own. $f$ is just an element in the bag of functions. In the bag of functions there is an element that is the identity for the operation, which is $i(x) = x$ and there is an element which is the inverse of $f$, namely $h(x) = x-2$: $f(h(x)) = h(f(x)) = x = i(x)$.

Comment: @RGS So, it seems that composition of functions is not the same as the simple examples of groups with only one possible action, say addition or multiplication on $\mathbb{Z}$. If so, then all the interesting examples would occur only in the domain of composition of functions.

Comment: @jiten the bag of all real-valued functions with the operation *composition* between functions **IS** a group. It is a group where the binary operation is neither addition of functions nor multiplication of functions, it is function composition. You did ask for a more complex example, and so I took a different group with a different operation. It is, still, a group.

Comment: @RGS Please tell me a source, to practice more, having enough examples, or have at least brief solutions. It can be upper level also, as can try.

Comment: @RGS It is regarding one of my earlier comments in which I implicitly stated the need to differentiate between (i) simple groups (based on set of actions) that can have some simple action as addition, multiplication on $\mathbb{Z}$; and (ii) composition of functions. In (i) there is a single operation, while in (ii) there is set (bag) of functions. In (i) the associativity means ordering of elements under the given binary operation (say $+$) gives same result; while for (ii) the action has changed from say $f(x) = x+2$ to $g(x) = x^2$, and same element must be subjected to both in diff. order.

Comment: @RGS I mean by the previous comment that in simple groups based on a single action, any three elements need be considered for the application of the property of associativity; while for function composition based groups, there is one element subjected to different  ordering of functions.