# Why need second condition to be a subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let H be a non-empty subset of a group G. Then H is a subgroup of G if and only if 
1) $a, b \in H$ implies that $ab \in H$, and 
 2) $a \in H$ implies $a^{−1} \in  H$.

I have confusion in the second point as closure is already implied by (1). Then what difference is introduced by (2), by stating that the inverse also is in the set formed by the action table of group.

Comment: Let your group be $\mathbb{Z}$ under addition. Notice that the non-negative integers is a non-empty subset which satisfies (1) but not (2).

Comment: It might be relevant that the OP has a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2619004/need-an-example-to-show-the-need-to-check-the-closure-property-for-being-a-subgr)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $G=(\mathbb Z,+)$ and $H=\mathbb N$. It satisfies the first condition, but not the second.

The point is that, unless $G$ is finite, you cannot get inverses or identity by only using closure.

A nice exercise is to prove that for finite groups, the first condition is actually enough.

Comment: Regarding the finite groups, my attempt to show that the first condition is enough is: as closure is there, and identity and hence there is an inverse to each element; so the inverse element must lie in the group. Can you please help guide me making it formal one.

Comment: @jiten If you have a finite group, then there exists some $n$ such that $a^n=e$. This implies that $a^{n-1}=a^{-1}$. Use the first condition to show that $a^{n-1} \in H$ and deduce from here that the second condition holds.

Comment: Superb, it is a fine way. Can I say it a trick to easily show by taking a special case of the order of element in a finite group.

Answer (score 2):

Because otherwise the subset wouldn't necessarily be a group. For instance, it would allow $\Bbb N\subseteq \Bbb Z$ to be a subgroup, even though it isn't a group. That is clearly unwanted. A sub-something ought to actually be that something, right? A subset should be a set, a subgroup should be a group, a sub-vectorspace (often just called subspace in context) should be a vector space, and so on.

Comment: I like how 6 of 8 answers (so far), along with a comment under the question, has basically the exact same counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

Take the subset $\mathbb{N}$ of the additive group $\mathbb{Z}$. Then by $(1)$ alone, it would be a subgroup. But this is not true, since the inverses of $a$, namely $-a$ are not contained.

Answer (score 1):

Even with closure, we may have $a \in H$ but $a^{-1} \notin H$ since $1)$ is not an *if and only if* statement. In this case, we cannot call $H$ a subgroup because there is an element $a$ in $H$ such that $a^{-1}$ is not in $H$ and this is against the definition of group.

Answer (score 1):

We want to define a subgroup such that the subgroup is itself a group. Since a group requires inverses, we need inverses in the subgroup as well.

Closure does not imply the existence of inverses. For example, consider the subset $\mathbb{N}$ (the natural numbers, including zero) of the group of integers $\mathbb{Z}$ under addition. $\mathbb{N}$ is closed under addition, but does not contain inverses.

Comment: But, when ascertaining a set of actions to be a group, then among the two properties of inverse and identity, we test for identity first, then for inverse. In the example of $\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{N}$ it is hence enough to check that the stated set has the same identity as $\mathbb{Z}$ or not.

Comment: @jiten A group needs both identity and inverses. In $\mathbb{N}$, we have the identity $0$, and it's the same identity as $\mathbb{Z}$. So far, it can be a subgroup. It's only when we check for inverses that it fails.

Answer (score 1):

$(2)$ is necessary because otherwise $\mathbb{N}$ would be a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$, for instance.
You can, however, prove everything with only two conditions:

1. $H\neq \emptyset$
2. $h,g \in H \Longrightarrow hg^{-1} \in H$

Can you see why  this second condition is more powerful than just closure under multiplication?

Comment: I understand that you have taken the multiplication operation symbolically to stand for any operation. The second condition is more powerful as if inverse exists, then the closure condition being a subset of that and hence automatically implies. But, a formal proof of the first condition being a subset of (ii) is requested.

Comment: Yes, I am writing the group operation as multiplication (although in $\mathbb{Z}$ it would be addition). My second condition is more powerful because if you assume it, then you also get closure under inversion and multiplication: $H \neq \emptyset \Rightarrow \exists x \in H \Rightarrow 1 = x x^{-1} \in H \Rightarrow \forall \ x \in H, x^{-1} = 1 x^{-1} \in H$. Moreover, $\forall \ x,y \in H, xy = x(y^{-1})^{-1} \in H$. Of course, when you are given a subset $H$ of $G$, you have to check either your 3 conditions or my 2 conditions, to see that $H$ is a subgroup

Answer (score 1):

The second condition is not implied by the first. For example the non negative integers as a subset of the additive group of integers satisfy the first property, but not the second. However, both statements are equivalent to: $\forall a,b\in H : a\cdot b^{-1}\in H$

Comment: Please elaborate as the last line is not clear to me.

Comment: An equivalent definition of a subgroup $H$ is: $H\subset G$ subgroup iff $\forall a,b\in H : a\cdot b^{-1}\in H$ .

Comment: It seems you mean that $\forall a,b \in H$ both $a\cdot b^{-1}, b\cdot a^{-1} \in  H$. Am I correct?

Comment: Only $a\cdot b^{-1}\in H$ is sufficient, since the identity element $e$ is in $H$ (take $b=a$, then $a\cdot a^{-1} = e \in H$). Then $e\cdot a^{-1} \in H$ implies the second statement.